# How to compute the overlapping ratio of two rotated rectangles?

Tags: opencv, geometry

Given two rectangles, and we know the position of four corners, widths, heights, angles.
How to compute the overlapping ratio of these two rectangles?
Can you please help me out?

Comment: I don't know OpenCV much but can you draw and overlay them in 2 different colours say red and blue then calculate the number of purple pixels?

Comment: @Mark Setchell, you can but this solution might be extremely expensive. You may need to render and count millions of pixels. Also this will reduce accuracy of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convenient way is by the [Sutherland-Hodgman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm) polygon clipping algorithm. It works by clipping one of the polygons with the four supporting lines (half-planes) of the other. In the end you get the intersection polygon (at worst an octagon) and find its area by the [polygon area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid) formula.

[image]

You'll make clipping easier by counter-rotating the polygons around the origin so that one of them becomes axis parallel. This won't change the area.

Note that this approach generalizes easily to two general convex polygons, taking O(N.M) operations. G.T. Toussaint, using the Rotating Caliper principle, reduced the workload to O(N+M), and B. Chazelle & D. P. Dobkin showed that a nonempty intersection can be detected in O(Log(N+M)) operations. This shows that there is probably a little room for improvement for the S-H clipping approach, even though N=M=4 is a tiny problem.

Comment: +1, but you have to mention that rotation of both rectangles should be done around same point. If it is not same point (for example each one is rotated around its own center) than the answer will be incorrect. This is a very common error.

Comment: To please @Michael Burdinov, I added that rotation be done around the origin, which makes the rotation formula the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Use rotatedRectangleIntersection function to get contour and use contourArea function to get area and find the ratios

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#rotatedrectangleintersection

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have rectangle A and B the you can use the operation:

```
 intersection_area =  (A & B).area();
```

from this area you can calculate de respective ratio towards one of the rectangles. there will be harder more dynamic ways to do this as well.

Comment: ^^ hehe, had the same idea, but not so for **RotatedRect**

Comment: right, in that case and since we know the points of each rectangle.
Draw each one in a different Mat with same size of the original image.
Then do a AND operator and count the non Zero pixels of the output.
This will give you the number of pixels that both shapes share